# How can I find records from today, yesterday and so on with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord, date

I want to find all records, say Posts, created today with Ruby on Rails, then all Posts created yesterday, and so on… how should I do?

Thank you,

Kevin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Today
Posts.find(:all, conditions: { :created_at => Date.today...Date.today + 1 })
#Yesterday
Posts.find(:all, conditions: { :created_at => Date.today - 1...Date.today })
```

Or this (preferable, in my opinion):

```
#Today
Posts.find(:all, conditions: ["DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today] )
#Yesterday
Posts.find(:all, conditions: ["DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today - 1] )
```

Comment: I recently discovered that Date.today can equal Date.tomorrow and Date.today can equal Date.yesterday depending on timezone set.    Date.today uses box time (usually utc) and Date.tomorrow and yesterday use Time.zone so be careful.   Date.current uses Time.zone and should be used in place of Date.today

Answer (score 1):

As a rule I store all dates on my server in UTC timezone and let the UI handle any timezone conversion.
To get the sort of query you are after to work correctly I had to massage the incoming date into a
UTC specific time range first.

```
require 'date'

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.created(a_date)
    return Post.where(created_at: to_timerange(a_date))
  end

  private

  def self.to_timerange(a_date)
    raise ArgumentError, "expected 'a_date' to be a Date" unless a_date.is_a? Date
    dts = Time.new(a_date.year, a_date.month, a_date.day, 0, 0, 0).utc
    dte = dts + (24 * 60 * 60) - 1
    return (dts...dte)
  end

end
```

This then allows you to call

```
# today
posts = Post.created(Date.today)
# yesterday
posts = Post.created(Date.today - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To query using a range I prefer the following:

```
yesterday = Date.yesterday
start = yesterday.beginning_of_day
#Fri, 27 Nov 2020 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
end = yesterday.end_of_day
# Fri, 27 Nov 2020 23:59:59 UTC +00:00 - the value here is one second before midnight
# meaning we should use an inclusive range using two dots:
range = start..end

Post.where(created_at: range)
```