# Return table columns done today and yesterday in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, time

I am trying to get the records created only today, yesterday, and the day before yesterday. My model is **Visitor**

For items created today, I am trying

```
Visitor.where(created_at: Date.today)
```

And then for items created yesterday, I am trying

```
Visitor.where(created_at: Date.yesterday)
```

But then it is not working because the Created_at column is in form of a timestamp, while Date.today or yesterday is in a date format. How can I make this work.
And also how can I get the items creates the day before yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Today
Visitor.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today)
#Yesterday
Visitor.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.yesterday)
```

Alternatively:

```
#Today
Visitor.where(created_at: Date.today...Date.today+1)
#Yesterday
Visitor.where(created_at: Date.yesterday...Date.today)
```

Ref: [How can I find records from today, yesterday and so on with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570740/how-can-i-find-records-from-today-yesterday-and-so-on-with-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I was missing the comma, for the day before yesterday you can use Visitor.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.yesterday-1). It works.thanks

Comment: Do not use `Date.today`, etc as they do not take into account the time zone.

Answer (score 1):

To get visitors created after a certain time, for example the last 2 days:

```
Visitor.where(["created_at > ?", 2.days.ago.midnight])
```